# Displaying Data from a Google Fusion Table in a Table

Tags: json, api, google-fusion-tables

I am new to google fusion tables and was on the google developer website looking at examples. I made my own fusion table and tried to sub it in and it did not work. Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dansker/xzrc31gp/. I think it is not working because of this: 
    `"dataSourceUrl": "//www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=",`

What would I put in place of the "//www.google.com?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've only loaded the jsapi, but you must also load the visualization-library:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xzrc31gp/2/